# Iterating over an array of hashes in a Chef ERB template

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to build a recipe for chef that has amongst others the following attribute:

```
default['web-server']['hosts'] = [ { host: "some-ip", server: "some-server", port: "9000" } ]
```

The idea is to iterate over it to create the config file (lighttpd in this case), like so:

```
<% if node['web-server']['hosts'].length > 0 -%>
<%   node['web-server']['hosts'].each do |host| -%>

  $HTTP["host"] =~ "<%= host.host %>" {
    proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = (
      "" => (
          "play" => (
             "host" => "<%= host.server %>",
             "port" => <%= host.port %>
           )
         )
     )
  }
<%   end -%>
<% else -%>
<% end -%>
```

However, upon running `chef-client` on the test node, I am greeted with:

```
FATAL: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError: undefined method `host' for #<Mash:0x00000002b9a878>
```

What's the correct way of looping over an array of hashes?

Comment: You probably don't need to check if the `array.length > 0` because the method of `array.each` will automatically loop over everything.  If there is nothing in the array the `array.each` method will finish immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured this out. The correct syntax is to access the hash keys via `hash[:key]`, i.e.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "<%= host[:host] %>" {
    proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = (
         "" => (
             "play" => (
               "host" => "<%= host[:server] %>",
               "port" => <%= host[:port] %>
             )
         )
       )
  }
  <%   end -%>
  <% else -%>
  <% end -%>
```